# Angular animate don't add ng-hide-add and ng-hide-add-active

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js" defer></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js" defer></script>
    <!-- Own script section -->
    <script src="app.js" defer></script>
    <!-- CSS section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
<body ng-app="MainApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController as mainCtrl">
        <span class="test" ng-init="showSpan=true" ng-click="showSpan=false" ng-show="showSpan">Test</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js :

```
(function() {
    angular.module('MainApp', ['ngAnimate'])
        .controller('MainController', function() {

        });
})();
```

Style :

```
.test {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.test.ng-hide-add {
    opacity: 1;
}
.test.ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

Angular should add to span after click ng-hide-add and also ng-hide-add-active but this does not happen. Why?? I use newest angular and angular-animate. Angular only add ng-hide after click.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, I must used angular-animate 1.4.3, probebly in 1.4.4 there are changes that I yet not see

Answer (score 0):

**showSpan** is not created in the controller.

```
(function() {
    angular.module('MainApp', ['ngAnimate'])
        .controller('MainController', function($scope) { /* dont forget to call $scope here */
          $scope.showSpan = true; /* this must exists */
        });
})();
```

[Look](http://plnkr.co/edit/xwbf7qs06J6r5zR7wxkV)!

Comment: I observed that the same code that I post work on plunker but on my pc dont, very strange

Answer (score 0):

You are missing .ng-hide-add in finishing css (.test.ng-hide-add-active css).

http://plnkr.co/edit/dtyTHz30EiFV4PEjMWN8?p=preview

```
.test.ng-hide-add {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the hide animation */
.test.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
  transition: 1s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is it not working..you are expecting to fade away right?

Comment: When I fire my app with webstorm on localhost angular dont add to span class ng-hide-add, ng-hide-add-active. On plunker the same example works ok.

Answer (score 0):

When I use this:

```
 <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.0" data-semver="1.4.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

everything work correct, problem is with angular distribution.